# logistic / sigmoid function implementation numerical precision

Tags: python, scipy, floating-point, precision, sigmoid

in `scipy.special.expit`, logistic function is implemented like the following:

```
if x < 0
    a = exp(x) 
    a / (1 + a) 
else 
    1 / (1 + exp(-x))
```

However, I have seen implementations in other languages/frameworks that simply do

```
1 / (1 + exp(-x))
```

I am wondering how much benefit the scipy version actually brings.

For very small `x`, the result approaches to 0. It works even if `exp(-x)` overflows to `Inf`.

Comment: It seems that none of the answers given actually address the question. Is `1 / (1 + exp(-x))` accurate or not?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's really just for stability - putting in values that are very large in magnitude might return unexpected results otherwise.

If `expit` was implemented just as `1 / (1 + exp(-x))` then putting a value of `-710` into the function would return `nan`, whereas `-709` would give a value close to zero as expected. This is because `exp(710)` is too big to be a double.

The branching in the code just means that this scenario is avoided.

See also [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22006650/scipy-expit-unexpected-behavour-nans) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your point... stability is cited as the motivation for the code in [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/3386).

Comment: What I was trying to say, `1 / (1 + exp(-710))` doesn't return `NaN`, it returns 0 in IEEE standard as `1 / Inf = 0`. And it is true in numpy  `1 / (1 + np.exp(-710)) == 0`

Comment: But the problem is surely for `expit(x)` where `x` is some large-magnitude *negative* value. For instance `expit(-710)` needs to calculate the exponent of positive 710, i,e. `exp(+710)`. The `exp` in the source code I *think* refers to your system's C math library `exp` (not the ufunc `np.exp`) which will raise an error if overflow is detected, as is the case here.

Answer (score 4):

Seems it would be more efficient to use:

```
if x < -709
  sigmoid = 0.0
else
  sigmoid = 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-x))
```

unless you need number with 10^-309 precision (see below) which seems overkill!

```
>>> 1 / (1 + math.exp(709.78))
5.5777796105262746e-309
```

Comment: Not necessary, since `exp(710)` evaluates to infinity and `1 / (1 + inf) = 0` in floating point

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it would be

`python
np.where(x > 0, 1. / (1. + np.exp(-x)), np.exp(x) / (np.exp(x) + np.exp(0)))`

Since `np.exp(x) / (np.exp(x) + np.exp(0))` is equivalent to `1. / (1. + np.exp(-x))` but more stable for negative values